# High contrast theme causes missing icons

Tags: 16.04, unity, themes, system-settings, accessibility

**System Settings** will lose icons if the **Appearance > Theme** is set to *High Contrast*. The Launcher can also lose some icons. Changing back to the default *Ambiance* will restore icons after a while but not necessarily immediately.

How can *High Contrast* be used without the loss of icons?

This pertains to Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-themes-standard/+bug/1644662) there where the fix was just released days ago !

Ugrade your packages to these versions and it should fix your issues

```
xenial:
gnome-themes-standard | 3.18.0-2ubuntu2
gnome-accessibility-themes | 3.18.0-2ubuntu2
```

However, these are in the repository **xenial-proposed** currently.

You might want to add the following with your favourite editor

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

replace "us" with the country where you are

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main universe multiverse
```

then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and to upgrade only these packages do

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-standard gnome-accessibility-themes
```

then i would suggest to comment out the `proposed` reposoitory, as to not upgrade other packages

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add a `#` before the line

```
#deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main universe multiverse
```

and update again

```
sudo apt-get update
```